# Certificate for <x.x.x.x> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity Server as a internal key manager of wso2 api manager and use Shared_db and start two server based on documentation [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/) I got this error in api manager

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.exception.GlobalThrowableMapper} - An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper. feign.RetryableException: Certificate for <x.x.x.x> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [localhost] executing GET https://x.x.x.x:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration.
```

x.x.x.x is The Identity Server ip.

Answer (score 1):

The error simply indicated that the certificate you have for IS has the CN `localhost` and you are trying to access it with a different host(In this case IP) which causes the [hostname verification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) to fail.

The correct solution to resolve this issue is to create proper certificates with correct CN/SAN names and use one of them to access Identity Server.

As a workaround, although it's not recommended, you can try disabling hostname verification by adding the following properties to the server startup script.(Not sure what's the exact parameter that will do the trick, but try following)

```
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true \
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll \
-Dfeign.httpclient.disableSslValidation=true \
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr, It didn't work in last version of api manager and identity server, I think I should create custom CA.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue when upgrading from IS 5.11.0 to 6.0.0.

The SSL certificates generated with Letsencrypt didn't have `localhost` as a Security Alternative Name (SAN). The workaround with self-signed certificates that include `localhost` as SAN is ok, but not what we needed.

We have bypassed it by adding the `internal_hostname` parameter under the [server] block inside the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` config file:

```
[server]
hostname = "is.wso2.com"
internal_hostname = "is.wso2.com"
```

Make sure you replace `is.wso2.com` with your DNS.
More details can be found here.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/change-the-hostname/